# How I can proceed each member of lambda expression with a Function that return value using delegate?

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

I use Vb.net in my work. I find a difficulty when trying to delegate a Function that returns value into each member of lambda expression.

I can do if for each member of lambda is delegated into a Sub:

```
Public class TransactionX
    Public Number1 as Integer 
    Public Number2 as Integer
end class

Public Class TestX

Public Sub DoTest()
    Dim trans as New List(Of TransactionX)
    trans.Add(New TransactionX with{.Number1=0, .Number2=0})
    trans.Add(New TransacrtionX with{.Number1=1, .Number2=1})

    dim changeNumber = New Action(Of TransactionX)(AddressOf DoChange)
    dim transSearch = trans.Where(Function(t) t.Number1>0).ForEach(changeNumber)
 end Sub

 Private Sub DoChange(ByVal tranX as TransactionX)
    with tranx
      .Number1 = 10
      .Number2 = 10
    end with
 end Sub
end Class
```

above code will update each member of lambda expression's result. 
What if I want to do Number1 * Number2 for each member that I catch from Lambda with a private Function and then will return into a collection? 
I think it can be done with C# but I could not solve it using Vb.net.

Comment: In that case you would call `Select` rather than `ForEach`.

Answer (score 0):

Change you method to return calculated value and use it with `Select` extension method

```
 Private Function DoChange(ByVal tranX As TransactionX) As Integer
     Return tranX.Number1 * tranX.Number2
 End Function

 Dim transSearch As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = trans.Select(AddressOf DoChange)
```

Use `AddressOf` keyword for passing existed method as parameter